# java - throw error out of the program

Tags: java

Inside my code I have several throw statements: `throws IOException`, `URISyntaxException`, `InterruptedException` etc.). Every time there are errors, the program stops running and exits. How can I catch those errors without closing up the program?

Comment: Use a `try-catch` block.

Comment: note that `throw` throws and exception, used via `throw new MyException()` versus `throws` which is the statement used to indicate that a function actually might throw an exception.

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a `try-catch` block. Imagine you have some method that throws an exception:

```
public void someMethod() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

To call that method and handle the exception, you might do something like this:

```
try {
    someMethod();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle the exception here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trace the problem that is causing the error. This is done with a `try-catch` block. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html). There is a simple statement that allows you to display the error on your console, `printstacktrace();`. Here is a non-working example of something like this:

```
try {

      //Check some suspicious code here:
      aMethod();

    } catch(Exception e) {

            //Handle the evil code here:
            System.out.println("Error! Error! Stupid organic:");
            e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Inside the `try` body, you will write code. The code will be executed as normal, except that a specified exception will be thrown. Inside the `catch` body, though, you will write exception handling code. If the code inside the `try` makes the compiler mad, the compiler will refer to the `catch` instead. There is another block that is not as common as the mentioned, the `finally`. The code inside that body will ALWAYS be executed if the `try` catches an exception. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html).

Finally, I'll recommend you two different links. The [first](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) one redirects you to the exceptions doc, the [second](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm) one redirects you to a good article about exceptions handling on tutorialpoint.com